# select XML attribute and pop into a table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

I am tring to make a button that user can select to filter the stores they want and see the result in a table. for example, select XML rows with state attribute equals to A. But nothing returned, please advise if any syntax has problems. Thanks.

```
<markers>
<marker name="Store A" address="1 ABC street" state="A" phone="1234567"  />
<marker name="Store B" address="2 ABC street" state="B" phone="1234567"  />
<marker name="Store C" address="3 ABC street" state="A" phone="1234567"  />
```

```
<input type='button' name='select1' value="A" onClick="changeFilter(this.value);">

function changeFilter(ctry){
$country=ctry;              
$(".datarow").remove();     
loadTable($xmldata);        
}


function loadTable(data){
$xmldata=data;                  
$(data).find("marker[state=" + ctry + "]").each(function(){ 

    var $this=$(this);                          
    var $name=$this.find('marker[name]').text();    
    var $tel=$this.find('marker[phone]').text();    
    var $country=$this.find('marker[address]').text();  

    $("#datatable").append("<tr class='datarow'><td>"+$name+"</td><td>"+$tel+"</td><td>"+$country+"</td></tr>"); 
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.attr()` get method inorder to get the attribute value.

```
$("div").find("marker[state=" + ctry + "]").each(function(){ 
 var $this=$(this);    
    var $name=$this.attr("name");    
    var $tel=$this.attr("phone");    
    var $country=$this.attr("address");  

});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zjgx2pcj/8/)

Comment: Hi Anoop, that worked fine, but when I added to my code, it doesn't return anything. mind have a look at and help on https://jsfiddle.net/sf2mnnjL/  please

Comment: Hi Anoop, Thanks a lot for your help! it did take a while but I fixed it. Thanks!